# How to set UICollectionViewCell Width and Height programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a `CollectionView`.
When I am using Autolayout, my cells won't change the size, but their alignment.

Now I would rather want to change their sizes to e.g.

```
var size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/10, height: self.view.frame.width/10)
```

I tried setting in my `CellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
collectionCell.size = size
```

it didn't work though.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**edit**:

It seems, that the answers will only change my CollectionView width and height itself. Is there are conflict in Constraints possible? Any ideas on that ?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

Use this method to set custom cell height width.

**Make sure to add this protocols**

```
UICollectionViewDelegate

UICollectionViewDataSource

UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

If you are using **swift 5** or **xcode 11** and later you need to set `Estimate Size` to `none` using storyboard in order to make it work properly. If you will not set that than below code will not work as expected.

[image]

> **Swift 4 or Later**

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    //Write Delegate Code Here
}

extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    //Write DataSource Code Here
}

extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth)
    }
}
```

> **Objective-C**

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame), (CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame)));
}
```

Comment: somehow it doesn't change my cells, but more like my CollectionView

Comment: you also need to set cell property to custom from storyboard design

Comment: Unfortunately still changes the CollectionView size

Comment: set this cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame)/4, (CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame)/4));
}

Comment: see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296759/when-app-in-background-and-receiving-push-notification-tap-app-goes-crash?noredirect=1#comment77555738_45296759

Comment: I'm so used to doing everything programmatically that this seems so foreign to me now. In Storyboard setting **Estimated Size** to **None** and adding the **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** is what does the trick

Comment: It's work for me. neigher the storyboard's Cell Size in collectionView nor item size's setting in protocol don't work, as long as set the estimate size automatic

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. *But* can someone please explain **WHY** we have to set `Estimate Size` to `None`........?

Comment: @LanceSamaria did you find a way to set programmatically or did you go with storyboard?

Comment: @henrique I do everything programmatically, it’s just easier. Add the protocol: `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and then to set the cell's size use: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight) }`

Comment: @LanceSamaria that's what I'm doing but it's not working for some reason, my `sizeForItemAt` is never called. Delegate is properly set. I wanted to test the suggested solution setting it to None but I'm not using storyboards.

Comment: @henrique can you make a public GitHub with a **simple** version of whatever you're doing. Send me the link here and I'll take a look at it. Whatever you're doing wrong I'll fix it and add some comments to show you where you're going wrong.

Comment: `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` already conforms to `UICollectionViewDelegate`. Remove extra code

Answer (score 100):

If one is using storyboard and overriding **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** then in swift 5 and Xcode 11 also set **Estimate size to None**
[image]

Comment: That was definitely what I was about to crazy. Unless you set it to none, you are unable to see the correct size that you have given in sizeForItem method.

Comment: Good fix. Here's my diagnosis of this issue according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1779556-automaticsize): `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` seems to default `estimatedItemSize` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` when using IB even though the documentation says it should default to `CGSizeZero`. As Apple states, `automaticSize` "enables self-sizing cells for your collection view." That's why other size changes in IB do nothing.

Answer (score 79):

Make sure to add the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in your `class` declaration

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    //MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
       return CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forgot to use flow layout and not custom. Then yours is the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: how can we give dynamic height here giving static height as 100.0

Answer (score 23):

Finally got the answer.
You should extend `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` 
This should be working with answers above.

Comment: Could you write an example?

Comment: Actually I made an extension with both datasource and delegateFlowLayout protocols and it did not work. What worked was separating the FlowLayout part to an extension of its own. Not sure why but it worked in swift 3.

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 4**

You have 2 ways in order to change the size of CollectionView.
**First way** -> add this protocol **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** 
for
In my case I want to divided cell into 3 part in one line. I did this code below

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
            // In this function is the code you must implement to your code project if you want to change size of Collection view
            let width  = (view.frame.width-20)/3
            return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return collectionData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        if let label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel {
            label.text = collectionData[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Second way** -> you **don't** have to add **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** but you have to write some code in **viewDidload function** instead as code below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: UICollectionView!
        var collectionData = ["1.", "2.", "3.", "4.", "5.", "6.", "7.", "8.", "9.", "10.", "11.", "12."]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let width = (view.frame.width-20)/3
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width) 
    }
}
```

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
   

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return collectionData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        if let label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel {
            label.text = collectionData[indexPath.row]
        }
   
        return cell
    }
}
```

Whatever you write a code as the first way or second way you will get the same result as above.  I wrote it.  **It worked for me**

[image]

Comment: Straight from raywenderlich.com 

Answer (score 14):

**Size ratio according to iPhone size :**

Here's what you can do to have different width and height for cell's regarding the iPhone size :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (self.view.frame.size.width - 12 * 3) / 3 //some width
    let height = width * 1.5 //ratio
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

And maybe you should also disable your AutoLayout constraints on cell for this answer to work.

Comment: I tried this and all the above solutions but the contents in a cell are not autoresizing, how can I fix this

Answer (score 11):

in **Swift3** and **Swift4** you can change cell size by adding **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** and implementing it's like this :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
```

or if create UICollectionView programmatically you can do it like this :

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
                    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal //this is for direction
                    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0 // this is for spacing between cells
                    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height) //this is for cell size
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

Answer (score 7):

The collection view has a *layout* object. In your case, it is probably a *flow layout* ([UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html)). Set the flow layout's `itemSize` property.

Comment: Tried this. gives me the same issue like before. somehow my CollectionView changes it size rather than my cells.

Comment: Well, it all depends _when_ you do it. You have not shown your real code, so who knows what you're doing? I assure you it does work.

Answer (score 5):

swift4 swift 4 ios collection view collectionview example xcode latest code working sample

Add this on Delegate section of the top

UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

and use this function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (self.view.frame.size.width - 20) / 3 //some width
    let height = width * 1.5 //ratio
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

/////
sample complete code

create on collection view and collectionview cell in storyboard give reference to the collection as
@IBOutlet weak var cvContent: UICollectionView!

paste this in View controller

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var arrVeg = [String]()
    var arrFruits = [String]()
    var arrCurrent = [String]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cvContent: UICollectionView!
    
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arrVeg = ["Carrot","Potato", "Tomato","Carrot","Potato", "Tomato","Carrot","Potato", "Tomato","Carrot","Potato", "Tomato"]
        
        arrVeg = ["Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Orange"]
        
        
        arrCurrent = arrVeg
    }
    //MARK: - CollectionView
    


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (self.view.frame.size.width - 20) / 3 //some width
        let height = width * 1.5 //ratio
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        
        return arrCurrent.count
    }
    
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor.green
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 5 Programmatically

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        //Provide Width and Height According to your need
        let cellWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 10
        let cellHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 10
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)

        //You can also provide estimated Height and Width
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)

        //For Setting the Spacing between cells
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

        return UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }()
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

**A Complete programmatically solution**

```
// In viewDidLoad
    if let cvLayout = horizontalCV.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        cvLayout.estimatedItemSize = .zero
    }


extension TUIViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width)/7, height:50)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
    
}
```

Bonus : Handles when device rotates ::

```
  override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
        // Have the collection view re-layout its cells.
        coordinator.animate(
            alongsideTransition: { _ in self.horizontalCV.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() },
            completion: { _ in }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Seems redundant and counterintuitive that you have to add `cvLayout.estimatedItemSize = .zero` to tell iOS "no really, respect the cell size I'm giving you", but it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

Add these protocols

```
 - `UICollectionViewDelegate`
   
   
 - `UICollectionViewDataSource`
   
 
 - `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`
```

Your code will then look like this

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    //Write Delegate Code Here
}

extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    //Write DataSource Code Here
}

extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth)
    }
}
```

Now the final and crucial step to see this take effect is to go to your viedDidLoad function inside your Viewcontroller.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collection.dataSource = self // Add this
        collection.delegate = self // Add this
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Without telling your view which class the delegate is it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you need to keep your custom flow layout's `itemSize` dynamically updated based on your collection view's width, you should override your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s `prepare()` method. Here's a [WWDC video demoing this technique](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/225/?time=707).

```swift
class MyLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        
        itemSize = CGSize(width: ..., height: ...)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An other way is to set the value directly in the flow layout

```
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
```

Answer (score 1):

## A simple way:

If you just need a **simple fixed size**:

```
class SizedCollectionView: UIICollectionView {
    override func common() {
        super.common()
        let l = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        l.itemSize = CGSize(width: 42, height: 42)
        collectionViewLayout = l
    }
}
```

That's all there is to it.

In storyboard, just change the class from UICollectionView to SizedCollectionView.

## But !!!

Notice the base class there is "UI 'I' CollectionView".  'I' for Initializer.

It's not that easy to add an initializer to a collection view. Here's a common approach:

## Collection view ... with initializer:

```
import UIKit

class UIICollectionView: UICollectionView {
    private var commoned: Bool = false
    
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        super.didMoveToWindow()
        if window != nil && !commoned {
            commoned = true
            common()
        }
    }
    
    internal func common() {
    }
}
```

In most projects, you need "a collection view with an initializer". So you will probably anyway have `UIICollectionView` (note the extra I for Initializer!) in your project.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to setting from storyboard for attribute for collectionView in cell section estimate Size to none, and in your ViewController you need had delegate method for implementing this method : `optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`

Comment: How do you set `Estimate size to None` programmatically if you're not using IB?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method. In Xcode 11 or later, you need to set Estimate Size to none from storyboard.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let padding: CGFloat =  170
    let collectionViewSize = advertCollectionView.frame.size.width - padding
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2)
}
```

Comment: How do you set `Estimate size to None` programmatically if you're not using IB?

Answer (score 1):

#### Absolutely simple way:

```
class YourCollection: UIViewController,
     UICollectionViewDelegate,
     UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

#### You must add "UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout" or, there is no autocomplete:

```
class YourCollection: UIViewController,
     UICollectionViewDelegate,
     UICollectionViewDataSource,
     UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

#### Type "sizeForItemAt...". You're done!

```
class YourCollection: UIViewController,
     UICollectionViewDelegate,
     UICollectionViewDataSource,
     UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
 
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
      sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     
     return CGSize(width: 37, height: 63)
}
```

#### Recall that you must set estimated size as "none" in all cases.

It's just one of those stupid things about UIKit that setting "estimated size" as "none" in fact means "I will supply the size, do not override the sizes I give".

The "none" option should be called, say, "explicit" or "manual" or "set in code".

***(Also don't forget that "none" on the storyboard, is ".zero" in code.)***

Additionally, "none" is not the default, which is very confusing. There are very few cases where you use anything other than "none"

Note that you can simply set "estimated size" as "none" on the storyboard ... when you add a collection view on storyboard, it comes with a collection view layout inside it:

[image]

Tap ON the collection view layout (not the collection view) and ...

[image]

That's it, you're done.

#### For example:

Example, if you want "each cell fills the whole collection view":

```
     guard let b = view.superview?.bounds else { .. }
     return CGSize(width: b.width, height: b.height)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5, Programmatic UICollectionView setting Cell width and height**

```
// MARK: MyViewController

final class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    private lazy var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let spacing: CGFloat = 1
        let numOfColumns: CGFloat = 3
        let itemSize: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - (numOfColumns - spacing) - 2) / 3
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)
        return layout
    }()
    
    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureCollectionView()
    }
    
    private func configureCollectionView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        collectionView.register(PhotoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell")
    }
    
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
    
}

// MARK: PhotoCell

final class PhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init?(coder:) not implemented")
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(imageView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using UICollectionViewController, you need to add conformance to it by setting delegates UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

```
  extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

After that, you have to set a delegate to your collection view that is added to ViewController.

```
  collectionView.delegate = self
  collectionView.dataSource = self
```

And finally, you have to add layout to your collection view:

```
  let collectionLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionLayout
```

After these steps, you can change size in func:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for storyBoard users is: "In size inspector change your collection cell size from custom to Automatic".

[image: screenshot link]

Answer (score -4):

This is my version, find your suitable ratio to get the cell size as per your requirement.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame)/4, CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame)/4); 
}
```