# When App in Background and receiving push notification tap App goes crash

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, xamarin.ios, background-mode

I am working on Push Notification with Azure Notification Hub.

I want to start my app from AppDelegate where the Notification is Tap.

Here is the Scenario, How I can open my App.

**AppDelegate.cs** file

```
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        private SBNotificationHub Hub { get; set; }

        public bool appIsStarting = false;

        public SlideoutNavigationController Menu { get; private set; }


        public override UIWindow Window
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            if (launchOptions != null)
            {
                // check for a remote notification
                if (launchOptions.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey))
                {

                    NSDictionary remoteNotification = launchOptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as NSDictionary;
                    if (remoteNotification != null)
                    {
                        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
                        Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();

                        var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
                        var webController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("DashBoardViewController") as DashBoardViewController;

                        Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(webController, Menu);
                        Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new DummyControllerLeft(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = false };

                        Window.RootViewController = Menu;
                        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
                    }
                }
                ReceivedRemoteNotification(application, launchOptions);

            }
            else
            {

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
            }

            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();

            return true;
        }
}
```

**UserNotificationCenterDelegate.cs** file

```
class UserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    {

        public SlideoutNavigationController Menu { get; private set; }



        #region Constructors
        public UserNotificationCenterDelegate()
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Override Methods
        public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            // Do something with the notification
            Console.WriteLine("Active Notification: {0}", notification);


            // Tell system to display the notification anyway or use
            // `None` to say we have handled the display locally.
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
        {
            base.DidReceiveNotificationResponse(center, response, completionHandler);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

I have tried all possible scenario which i found on google and So and other site but nothing is working for me.

I spent 4 days on this but not get success.

Any Help Will be Appreciated.

Comment: Have you put the logs also with breakpoint....?

Comment: can you share what is the crash log when you try to open.?

Comment: @GouravJoshi I am testing on the Release mode so breakpoint isn't work.

Comment: @NitinGohel i am testing on the Release mode so crash log is not display

Comment: check after removing didFinish launch code to set a new root if notification found that wont crash. so you need to move that code in DidReceiveNotificationResponse or other notification delegate.

Comment: you mean say if `remoteNotification` is found then i want to set Root to in this method `DidReceiveNotificationResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in DeviceLogs **Window->Devices->View Device Logs**? There must be crash logged.

Comment: Use any framework like Crashlytics,SplunkMint .It really helps in logging crashes on the go.

Comment: I am deploy in Release mode so no Option available.

Comment: Just for information sake, don't you want to get crash reports from live app users?

Comment: Thanks for the Information but for that `Xamarin Profiler` is there.