# Collection View Cell Size/Fitting issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4, uicollectionviewlayout

I am working on an iOS app in swift 4. I have implemented collection view and there are two cells at the front as shown in the image: 
[image: CollectionViewCells-Image]

When I run my app on bigger screen sizes like iPhone 6/7/8 Plus, then it Shows two complete cells with one-half cell. What I want to achieve is that it shows two cells in front of every screen size, Please help.

Comment: Look for `optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set UICollectionViewCell Width and Height programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028013/how-to-set-uicollectionviewcell-width-and-height-programmatically)

Comment: try this :     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width , height:collectionView.frame.size.height/2)
    }

Comment: Tried this code but no success. Everything stays same.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol in your ViewController, then implement:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellSize = //calculate cell size based on the width of the view and padding between cells
    return cellSize
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) for the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement its methods to modify the spacing between the cells.