# Dynamically size both UICollectionViewCell and UICollectionView, maybe UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm building something as shown in the image below:

[image: horizontal list]

I'll try to explain a bit more what my goal is. I have a `UITableView`. One `UITableViewCell` `(1)` in here will contain a title (left out in this image) and a `UICollectionView` `(2)` (same width as tableview/screen). This collectionview uses a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` to make it horizontally scrollable, evenly spacing the items.

Each `UICollectionViewCell` `(3)` in here contain a title and description, both with dynamic heights. Also, this cell contains a new collectionview `(4)`. This new collectionview contains a number of items `(5)`. In this most inner collectionview a row can contain a maximum of 5 items.

Currently I have a tableviewcell `(1)` with horizontally scrollable collectionview `(2)`, putting the items `(3)` next to each other. I also have the most inner collectionview `(4)` putting the items `(5)` in the correct way.

The difficulty I'm facing now is:

- To dynamically size the height of collectionview `(4)`, depending on how many rows for the items are needed, so depending on the number of items.
- To dynamically size the height of collectionviewcell `(3)`, depending on the height of the title, description and collectionview `(4)`.
- If possible, to dynamically size the height of the collectionview `(2)` and the tableviewcell `(1)` containing this, as high as the biggest cell `(3)`.

I hope someone would have an idea how to do this, if it is even possible. I do hope so, while keeping the code 'easy' to follow.

I can do a lot with constraints / autolayout, but this I can't get my head around.

Comment: I wouldn't get caught up on dynamically sizing content. It's not too tough. I would recommend you break your problem down into bite size chunks starting from the innermost views outward. Make use of stack views. Less is more on the constraints. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028106/4475605

Comment: Wow, how I didn't know about the existence of `UIStackView`? I'll check that out! And yes, I'll try again starting on the innermost view. My biggest question now is how to give a `UICollectionView` a dynamic height.

Thanks!