# UIButton in Collection View Cell not receiving Touch Up Inside event

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to setup a Carousel-like UI with buttons in each carousel cell. I am using a Collection View to do this. The buttons show up in the cell, but do not seem to respond to the touch up inside event which should run `tapped()` and return "TAPPED!". Here is the code for the Collection View Cell which includes the button. Thanks for the help!

**CarouselCollectionViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class CarouselCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    static let identifier = "CarouselCollectionViewCell"

    @objc func tapped() {
      print("TAPPED!")
    }

    var mainView : UIView = {
      var mainCellView = UIView()
      mainCellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      return mainCellView
    }()

    var remindButton : UIButton = {
      var textView = UIButton()
      textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      return textView
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)

      self.addSubview(mainView)
      mainView.addSubview(remindButton)
      mainView.backgroundColor = .white

      //Style
      mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
      mainView.layer.masksToBounds = true

      // Constraints
      mainView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      mainView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
      mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 360).isActive = true
      mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 290).isActive = true

      self.remindButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 69.0/255.0, green: 198.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
      self.remindButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
      self.remindButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
      self.remindButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainView.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
      self.remindButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      self.remindButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
      self.remindButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 175).isActive = true
      self.remindButton.setTitle("Add Reminder", for: .normal)
      self.remindButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `collectionView` `cell` height and width are correct to contain the calculated height and width of `mainView`

Comment: I tried adding "self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 360).isActive = true" and "self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 360).isActive = true" to set cell height and width but to no avail

Comment: Try to change cell height and width using `collectionView` itself, and conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` refere to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028013/how-to-set-uicollectionviewcell-width-and-height-programmatically